# Multiple Hide and show div using jquery

Tags: jquery, mp3, audio-player

I want a Mp3 player [like this one.](http://mp3skull.com/mp3/love.html) My search script show 10 result per page. I want to insert an mp3 for every search result item.

1. When I click "play", the player opens fine, and when I click "Stop", the player stops fine, but when I click "Play" and click "Play" on another result,  the first one does not stops and the second one opens fine.
2. Also when I click "play" I need to play the mp3 automatically; When I click "stop" the player has to stop.

   ```
   <script>
   $(function(){ // DOM READY shorthand

    $(".player").hide();

    $('.playertext').click(function( e ){
    var SH = this.SH^=1; // "Simple toggler"
    $(this).text(SH?'Stop':'Play')
          .css({backgroundPosition:'0 '+ (SH?-18:0) +'px'})
          .next(".player").slideToggle();
   });

   });

   </script>
   ```

   html:

   ```
    <div id="home">
   <div  class="playertext">Play</div>

   <div class="player">
      <audio controls>
        <source       src="http://media.easyuploadservice.com/telugu%20mp3/Mahankali%20(2011)/01%20-%20%20Keechaka%20Vadha.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
      </audio>
    </div>

   <div  class="playertext">Play</div>

    <div class="player">
       <audio controls>
         <source src="http://media.easyuploadservice.com/telugu%20mp3/Mahankali%20(2011)/03%20-%20%20Oo%20Lala.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
      </audio>
    </div>

   </div>
   ```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naguchennai/18mb4j49/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying a few things. Please check if this is what you wanted: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/18mb4j49/7/)

```
$(".player").hide();
$('.playertext').click(function (e) {
    var $player_div = $(this).next(".player"),
        $player = $("audio", $(this).next(".player"));

    $(".player").not($player_div).each(function (index, item) {
        var $player = $(this),
            $text = $player.prev(".playertext");
        $text.get(0).SH = 0;
        if ($player.is(":visible")) {
            $player.slideToggle(function () {
                $text.text('Play');
            });
        }
        $("audio", this).get(0).pause();
    });

    var SH = this.SH ^= 1; // "Simple toggler"
    $(this).text(SH ? 'Stop' : 'Play')
        .css({
        backgroundPosition: '0 ' + (SH ? -18 : 0) + 'px'
    })
        .next(".player").slideToggle(function () {
        $(this).is(":visible") ? $player.get(0).play() : $player.get(0).pause();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes.. Thank you so much. only one error.. when playing first one if i click second one first text not changed .. both showing "stop"

Comment: you're right, let me have a look and I'll get back to you with an update

Comment: @Higginslpert ok, fixed it, please let me know if there's something else. I've updated the answer